# the ajax function is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

what my actual requirement is that i want to retrieve values returned from my aspx page to html page .
thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">



  function getCars() {
      alert("ji");
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:1967/WebSite14/Default.aspx",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "json",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {
              var cars = response.emp;
              alert("ji");
              $('#output').empty();
              $.each(cars, function (index, emp) {

                  $('#output').append('<p><strong>' + emp.Expiry + ' ' +
                            emp.Expiry + '</strong><br /> Year: ' +
                            emp.Expiry + '<br />Doors: ' +
                            emp.Expiry + '<br />Colour: ' +
                            emp.Expiry + '<br />Price: £' +
                            emp.Expiry + '</p>');
              });
          },
          failure: function (msg) {
              $('#output').append('hi');
          }
      });
  }
```

please help me, am i wrong some where this is what my aspx page returns and also i dont know what should i do to the success :function(response) please help me

```
    {
    "emp": [
        {
            "Name": "Apple",
            "Expiry": 1,
            "Price": 3.99,
            "Sizes": [
                "Small",
                "Mediu",
                "Large"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Apple",
            "Expiry": 1,
            "Price": 3,
            "Sizes": [
                "Small",
                "Mediu",
                "Large"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What's the problem ? Do you call getCars() ?

Comment: The title of your post says the `ajax()` function is not called. Presumably this is not what you meant and, in fact, there's some problem with the request/response itself? Does your success callback get called? Does it contain a response?

Comment: Your ajax request already returns the json (that json fragment is what your aspx page responded in the $.ajax call, right?), so what's the problem? I don't see you've parsed the returned json though.

Comment: @Utkanos     i am a new b please help me dont be harsh , i dont know what that response is for , i was trying a program from net . what my requirement is to display the data from the aspx page to the html page , am i missing anything please help me

Comment: @LeleDumbo my aspx page is not responding in that ajax call , neither the success function nor the failure function  is called , i tried it with some alert() in the respective functions

Comment: @user1386579 - I wasn't being harsh in any way, I am simply saying there are some fundamental things to check in order to ascertain where the problem lies. In your `success` callback, put `console.log('RESPONSE:');console.log(response)`. Then run the script, then look in the console. Do you see the response?

Comment: @Utkanos i know i am annoying u all with such beginner question , anyways i pasted console.log('RESPONSE:');console.log(response)
but there isnt any change or anything displayed

Comment: OK so the request is not returning successfully. Try adding an error handler as well as a success one. See the jQuery docs for `ajax()`.

Comment: You have to put a method, which want to use from code behind(Default.aspx), like as `url: 'Default.aspx/callingMethod'`..

Comment: @Wahid4sap you want me to write it inside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i went ahead with this format to get the data from the link , it worked , thank u guys for ur support

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        {
            alert(xmlHttp.status);
            if(xmlHttp.status==200)
            {

            alert("hi");
            var jsondata=eval("("+xmlHttp.responseText+")") //retrieve result as an JavaScript object
            jsonOutput=jsondata.message.result;
            alert(jsonOutput);

            InitializeLeadStorage()

        }
        }
```